# Filtering User Based on Multiple Organizational Unit GSuite Search API

Tags: python, google-workspace

I want to fetch a list of users that present in multiple Organizational Units. For single organization unit below code is working fine

```
query = "orgUnitPath:/OU-1"
admin_service_obj = self.connector_obj.build_service_obj("admin", "directory_v1", 
      self.delegated_credentials())
activities = admin_service_obj.users()
request = activities.list(domain=self.domain, maxResults=50, query=query)
results = request.execute()
```

but for multiple organization units none of them is working.

```
query = "orgUnitPath:/OU-1 OR orgUnitPath:/OU-2"
query = "orgUnitPath:'/OU-1 OR /OU-2'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you can not use OR for multiple parameters of the query. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users#:%7E:text=Multiple%20clauses%20are%20separated%20by%20whitespace%20and%20are%20implicitly%20joined%20by%20an%20AND%20operator.):

> Multiple clauses are separated by whitespace and are implicitly joined by an AND operator.

I have tested it with other queries like listing users with different email addresses or names and it does not work.